# Posso ter mais de um construtor por classe?

Tags: java

A pergunta é simples pessoal: Eu posso ter mais de um construtor em uma mesma classe?

Em um primeiro momento, eu precisarei definir a variável `plugin` no meu objeto, então vou usar o construtor que define tal variável;

```
public RankAPI(Main main) {

    plugin = main;

}
```

Porem, em um segundo momento, precisarei definir uma segunda variável, a variável `p` no meu objeto, então terei que usar o segundo construtor:

```
public RankAPI(Player player) {

    p = player;

}
```

Infelizmente, não posso definir as duas variáveis, pois a variável `p` será definida por outros programas quando precisarem acessar minha API, e a variável `plugin` será definida pelo meu próprio programa quando for executado.

Obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Não fará mais sentido separar em classes diferentes? Com esta abordagem tens de andar sempre a verificar qual está  set e qual não está. I

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pode. Só precisa definir parâmetros diferentes para eles (em tipos e quantidade), isso se chama *overload* (sobrecarga).

Ex.:

```
class MinhaClasse
{
    private int id;
    private String nome;

    public MinhaClasse() { }

    public MinhaClasse(String nome) { this.nome = nome; }

    public MinhaClasse(int id) { this.id = id; }

    public MinhaClasse(int id, String nome) { this.id = id; this.nome = nome; }
}
```

Comment: Ótimo, então estou fazendo o certo :)
Obrigado!

Comment: Vale lembrar que os delegates são diferentes inclusive pela quantidade, não só os tipos ...!

Comment: _Muchas gracias_.